# Why do we need to instantiate a type at run time?

Tags: reflection

I am new to the usage of reflection in Java/scala. It is not quite clear to me why we need to instantiate a type at runtime. An example would be the best. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a general example of where runtime type instantiation or in general inspection of a types is useful. Think of the [Plugin Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648205.aspx). Assume you want to create an application that allows users to create plugins. You don't have the plugins the users are going to make in the future, at hand. How are you able to use their plugins after you have released your application? You need to be able to inspect their plugins for a method your application requires and then call said method.

In order to enable this, language designers create a platform in which you are able to query a module (jar in java, assemblies in .net) for the types it defines and the methods, fields, etc it contains. You can then call any method, instantiate any type you want and basically interact with the module as if you had the module at compile time and you were referencing it(well not exactly but you get the point).

Here's and example of a method call that happens at runtime. You can assume that we have already created `foo` from a string we get from a configuration file at runtime. `foo` was specified as the name of the jar file containing the plugin types. I don't want to provide the instantiation code as it would make this too bloated, but here is the method:

```
Method method = foo.getClass().getMethod("doSomething", null);
method.invoke(foo, null);
```

As you see, we basically got the type of the class foo, we queried it for a method using the method's name and then called it. By doing so we extended the functionality of our program with the plugin at runtime.